# Disabling black underline on text in HTML input-field

Tags: html, css

I have a Cordova app that has a search field in a toolbar. It is a regular HTML input field with the borders hidden and background set to be transparent. When the user starts typing on Android (5.0), the current word is underlined in black, while the keyboard is offering up auto-complete suggestions. I have tried to set the following attributes on the input field:

```
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="search" ng-change="search()" ng-model="ident" placeholder="Search" style="text-decoration: none;">
```

This does not seem to fix the problem however. How can I prevent this behaviour?

[image: Black underline on text in HTML input field]

Comment: Why would you want to hide interaction clues? Have you also disabled autocomplete for your app?

Comment: The search terms the user will be entering are airport ICAO-codes (such as EHAM for Amsterdam), and autocorrect only gets in the way.

Comment: @Laurens I have same issue. have you got solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

use border-bottom instead of text-decoration:

```
a:link {
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

You can try adding this: `!important` right before the ; symbol.
This will give the code priority.

```
a:link {
text-decoration: none!important;
border-bottom: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a simple css

```
textarea {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

If you didn't, that's what I would recommend.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the swift reply. Unfortunately, as stated in the other answer, this does not get rid of it. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` to your input style.

Answer (score -1):

As you have said that it is simple HTML input textbox, the textarea code won't work.

Use this instead

```
<input type="text" style="text-decoration:none">
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the swift reply. Unfortunately, this does not get rid of it. I have updated the question to reflect this.